# monotonically decreasing probability distribution

Tags: distributions, exponential-distribution, genetics

I'm interested in modelling a process where, given $x_{1}<x_{2}$, then $P(x_{1})>P(x_{2})$, with $P(x)$ representing the density of the distribution at $x$. I know that the Exponential Distribution obeys to this, but can some one point out other's?

The variable I'm interested in is fitness, a population genetics concept. It is reasonable to assume that, if we assume a finite set of genotypes (combinations of genes) and plot the density of the fitness of all genotypes, this should have a higher density on the left, close to 0, and it should decrease.

The logic is that most combinations will be bad, but a smaller set will be good... In the extreme, there will be one combination with the best fitness, or a small set with the same maximum fitness.

Now, an Exponential distribution has this shape. However, I'm interested in what other distribution would make sense in this scenario... I do realize that the Gamma distribution can also fit, but it will have a region of parameters for which it's not decreasing

Comment: There would be *a lot* of distributions with that property!, for instance, some (not all) gamma distributions. Can you tell us something more about the variable you want to model?

Comment: I'm thinking about fitness (population genetics concept). It's reasonable to assume that many genotypes have a low fitness and few have high fitness - > meaning that many combinations of genes will be bad and a few will be good.

Comment: Good, you should edit that new information as part of the post, and not only as a comment, please. Also then consider adding the genetics tag!

Comment: You mention "maximum fitness" in your question so in case there is indeed some hard upper limit M for the value of the random variable one possibility is the family of scaled beta distributions M*Beta(1, b) with the free parameter b > 1.